# Allow Contributors to share files with users

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, share

We have a modern communication SharePoint online site, and we want to allow contributor users to share files with users (internal and external), so we found 2 approaches:-

1. Check the following checkbox:-
   [image]
2. or modify the Built-in Contribute permission level by checking the  "Manage Permissions" checkbox while leaving the above checkbox un-checked:-
   [image]

Based on our test the 2 approaches had allowed Contributor users to share files, so is there any differences between the 2 approaches i am unaware of?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big differences on these two methods from my point of view:

By using the first method, you will enable the sharing ability for items on **all site members** (*Edit* permission which does not have *Enumerate Permissions* included), by keeping the default site permission levels.

By using the second method, you will keep the site not-shareable for users, but enable the sharing ability **only for Contributors**. Site members with *Edit* permission (which is higher than *Contribute*) will still not be able to share documents to new users.

In addition, since you have changed the default permission level of *Contribute*, they will have corresponding access on other positions in this site as well.